# Set variable XYZ source and zoom delta depending on current viewZoom

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I've got a non-geographic map loading raster tiles from a custom XYZ source. I need to switch the XYZ source and the delta between two zoom steps (i. e. zoom by mouse wheel, keyboard, or click on +/- buttons) depending on the current fractional view zoom level.

For example like this:

```
#   viewZoom   source   {z}
-1  1.5    subdomain1   2
0   1.7    subdomain2   2
1   2.2    subdomain3   2
2   2.5    subdomain3   3
3   3.5    subdomain3   4
4   4.5    subdomain4   5
```

```
minZoom = 1.5; startZoom = 1.7
# indicating the number of zoom-ins beginning from the initial state
```

I've managed to load tiles from different subdomains using tileUrlFunction.

```js
const map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new XYZ({
        tileUrlFunction: function(tileCoord) {
            var subdomain;

            var viewZoom = map.getView().getZoom();
            if(viewZoom < 1.7) {
              subdomain = 'sub1';
            } else if(viewZoom < 2.2) {
              subdomain = 'sub2';
// ...
           }

            var z = tileCoord[0];
            var x = tileCoord[1];
            var y = tileCoord[2];    
           return 'https://mytileserver.org/' + subdomain + '/' + z + '/' + x + '/' + y + '.png';
        },
      })
    }),
  ],
});
```

However, tiles sometimes won't reload due to caching and zoom delta is always constant with this approach.

I'm hoping to find a more flexible solution. I'm a beginner with Openlayers having used Leaflet beforehand.

Comment: It would probably be easier to set up your view with a resolutions array instead of relying on the default delta and have two layers, one with a minResolution and the other with the same value as maxResolution

Comment: @Mike Setting the resolutions array worked great for controlling the zoom steps, thank you! However, switching between the two layers (using minResolution/maxResolution) is not smooth because with this method, the old layer is removed before the new layer is set, leaving a rather long time without any layer shown at all. Is it possible to create a smooth transition between the layers? I guess, it would be possible to listen to the moveend event and do the reload manually but perhaps there's an easier solution.

Comment: Are these opaque base layers?  If so you could try a small overlap between the minResolution/maxResolution and rely on the layer order or zIndex to keep one on top before the other disappears.